# Why is PC still 32 bits in Thumb mode on ARM processor?

Tags: arm

As Thumb mode can reference 16-bit of the general registers (r1-r14), why PC (r15) is still 32-bit? Will `b Label` in this mode update all 32 bits of PC, or just lower 16 bits?

Comment: The instruction length of thumb (version 1) is 16bit.  The addressing capabilities are not.  They are 32bit.  For instance, a byte instruction (early CISC/x86) did not support 256bytes of memory, but several 64k banks.  You are making machine/assembler instruction size equal to addressing (pointer) size.  They are not related at all.  It is a co-incidence they are the same for 32bit ARM.  Btw, r1-r14 are also 32bits in size, even in thumb mode.  In Thumb2, the instruction size is a mix of 16 and 32bits.

Answer (score 3):

Despite the question being based on an entirely incorrect premise, there *is* a cheeky sort-of-answer to the title question taken literally - being in Thumb mode means you're on a v4T or later architecture which means you must have a full 32 bits of PC, rather than the pre-v3 architectures where it was only 26 bits.

I'm not sure where you got the idea that Thumb operates on 16 bits of a register - the restriction with must Thumb instructions is that they can only access the "low registers" r0-r7, due to limited *encoding space*. There are 3 different "32-bit"s at play in ARM - the register width, the address space (which wasn't always the case as mentioned above), and the size of the fixed-width instruction encoding. Thumb only changes the third one. One result of this size reduction is that most Thumb encodings only have 3 bits per operand to encode register numbers - only a handful of instructions can spare the extra bits to encode the "high registers" r8-r15.

In operation, Thumb instructions are no different to the equivalent subset of ARM instructions - Thumb is just an alternative fetch/decode stage on the front of the same pipeline, after all.

Answer (score 2):

thumbv1 instructions are 16 bits in size but what does that have to do with the size of the registers?  (Nothing)  the registers including r15 are 32 bits all the time.  Branches with immediate values are simply offsets not absolute addresses.

this is all clearly documented in the ARM architectural reference manuals infocenter.arm.com

Comment: but in thumbv1, the instructions could only operate on 16-bit of the registers, right?

Comment: certainly not, for the armv4 and probably armv5 I dont know for sure bit it seems pretty obvious that they were simply converted to their 32 bit arm instructions and that was fed through the pipe.  nevertheless one thing has nothing to do with the other.  just like 8 bit x86 instructions dont only operate on 8 bits of the 64 bit registers, it depends on the instruction as to what the operation is.  when the arm doc talks about the register and does not isolate a bit range then the whole 32 bit register is what is being used

Comment: if you read the newer manuals with the unified syntax, just the notion of a unified syntax implies that thumb, thumb2 extensions or arm 32 bit instructions perform the same operations.  64 bit arm is completely different and incompatible btw, just talking about 32 bit armv4 to v7